# EventGrid Performance

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-eventgrid

I'm using event grid in our current project. I have created multiple topic endpoints for each event type and we ran out for space.
Now I would like to reuse the existing topics so I am planning for below two options.

1. One topic for few event types (Or)
2. Only one topic for all event types.

I have below questions/confirmation.

1. Performance affect If I go with the second approach so  Should I go and have one topic for few events or Should I keep only one topic.

Comment: What do you mean by `we ran out for space`?

Comment: have a look at the following links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50818555/multiple-eventtypes-in-azure-eventgrid-topic/50823312#50823312 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#azure-event-grid-limits